# Android Activity transfer not happening in a single time

Tags: android

Hello i build a small app using Android, in this app i built two activity and now when i click on my button(name of button New Game) of first activity to switch on second activity, it do nothing, but when i click on this button again it changes the activity. I want this in one click here i am posting code of my both activity please help me.
Thanks in advance
source code of first activity

```
public class TTTActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
public int result;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    View newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
    newButton.setOnClickListener(this);        

    View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
    exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}
private void quitApplication()
{
    finish();
}
private void startGame(){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Game.class));
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.new_button:
        //startNewGameConfirm();
        startGame();
        break;
    case R.id.exit_button:
        quitApplication();
        break;

    }

}
```

}

Source code of game activity

```
public class Game extends Activity {
private final int GAME_VICTORY = 0x1;
private final int GAME_DEFEAT = 0x2;
private final int GAME_TIE = 0x3;
private final int GAME_CONTINUES = 0x4;
private final float UNIQUE_MAX_WEIGHT=0.85f;
static final int ACTIVITY_SELECTION = 1;

private float[] w;  
private int[] c;        
private int[][] PosTable;   
private Button[] buttons;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);

    buttons = new Button[9];

    buttons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    buttons[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(0);
        }
    });
    buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    buttons[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(1);
        }
    });
    buttons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
    buttons[2].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(2);
        }
    });
    buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button04);
    buttons[3].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(3);
        }
    });
    buttons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button05);
    buttons[4].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(4);
        }
    });
    buttons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button06);
    buttons[5].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(5);
        }

    });
    buttons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button07);
    buttons[6].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(6);
        }
    });
    buttons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button08);
    buttons[7].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(7);
        }
    });
    buttons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button09);
    buttons[8].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(8);
        }
    });

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button10);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonsEnable(true);
           beginPlay();
        }
    });

  startActivityForResult(new Intent(Game.this, TTTActivity.class), ACTIVITY_SELECTION);


    DisplayMetrics dm = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float h = (float) (dm.heightPixels - (100.0)*dm.density);
    float w = dm.widthPixels;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
        buttons[i].setHeight((int) (h/3));
        buttons[i].setWidth((int) (w/3));
    }
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    beginPlay();
    if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_SELECTION) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras.getString("result").equals("CPU")) cpuPlay();
        }
    }
}
private void beginPlay() {
    //initializations start 
    w=new float[9];
    c=new int[9];
    InitTable();
    w[0]=0.7f;
    w[1]=0.4f;
    w[2]=0.7f;
    w[3]=0.4f;
    w[4]=0.7f;
    w[5]=0.4f;
    w[6]=0.7f;
    w[7]=0.4f;
    w[8]=0.7f;
    //c[i] : 0 for empty, 1 for cpu, 2 for user
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        c[i]=0;
    //initializations done

    //now we play!
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        updateBtn(i);
}

private void cpuPlay() {
    //computer plays first
    int cpos=getDecision();
    if (cpos == -1) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GAME OVER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }
    c[cpos]=1;
    updateBtn(cpos);
    int gstatus = CheckGameStatus();
    if (gstatus == GAME_VICTORY) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congrts You Won", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
    else if (gstatus == GAME_DEFEAT) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, You Lost", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
    else if (gstatus == GAME_TIE) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Its a TIE, press reset to play again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
    else if (gstatus == GAME_CONTINUES) {
        //user plays
    }
}
private void updateBtn(int i) {
    if(c[i]==0)
        buttons[i].setText(" ");
    else if(c[i]==1)
        buttons[i].setText("O");
    else
        buttons[i].setText("X");
}
private int CheckGameStatus() {
    int s = 0;
    //check horizontal
    if(c[0]==2&&c[1]==2&&c[2]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[3]==2&&c[4]==2&&c[5]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[6]==2&&c[7]==2&&c[8]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[0]==1&&c[1]==1&&c[2]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}
    if(c[3]==1&&c[4]==1&&c[5]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}
    if(c[6]==1&&c[7]==1&&c[8]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}
    //check vertical
    if(c[0]==2&&c[3]==2&&c[6]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[1]==2&&c[4]==2&&c[7]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[2]==2&&c[5]==2&&c[8]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[0]==1&&c[3]==1&&c[6]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}
    if(c[1]==1&&c[4]==1&&c[7]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}
    if(c[2]==1&&c[5]==1&&c[8]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}
    //check diagonal
    if(c[0]==2&&c[4]==2&&c[8]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[2]==2&&c[4]==2&&c[6]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[0]==1&&c[4]==1&&c[8]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}
    if(c[2]==1&&c[4]==1&&c[6]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}

    if (s != 0) {
        buttonsEnable(false);
        return s;
    }

    boolean box_empty = false;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if (c[i] == 0) box_empty = true;
    }
    if (box_empty) {    //if any box is empty -> game continues
        return GAME_CONTINUES;
    }
    else {  //else there is tie
        buttonsEnable(false);
        return GAME_TIE;
    }
}

private void buttonsEnable(boolean b) {
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        buttons[i].setEnabled(b);
}

private void btnClicked(int i) {
    if(c[i]!=0) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position occupied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
    else {
        //all OK
        c[i] = 2;
        updateBtn(i);
        int gstatus = CheckGameStatus();
        if (gstatus == GAME_VICTORY) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congrats You Won", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
        else if (gstatus == GAME_DEFEAT) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, You Lost", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
        else if (gstatus == GAME_TIE) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Its a TIE, press reset to play again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
        else if (gstatus == GAME_CONTINUES) {
            cpuPlay();
        }
    }
}

private int getDecision() {
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++) {
            if(c[i]==1&&c[j]==1)    //place 'o' to win
                if(PosTable[i][j]!=-1)  //if we have 3 in a row
                    if(c[PosTable[i][j]]==0)    //if position is free
                        return PosTable[i][j];
            if(c[i]==2&&c[j]==2)    //place 'o' to prevent user's victory
                if(PosTable[i][j]!=-1)  //if we have 3 in a row
                    if(c[PosTable[i][j]]==0)    //if position is free
                        return PosTable[i][j];
        }

    if(c[0]==1&&c[8]==0) return 8;
    if(c[2]==1&&c[6]==0) return 6;
    if(c[8]==1&&c[0]==0) return 0;
    if(c[6]==1&&c[2]==0) return 2;
    Random r=new Random();
    boolean exist07=false;
    boolean[] free=new boolean[9]; //will hold the free positions
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        free[i]=false;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        if(c[i]==0) {   //free ??
            free[i]=true;   //add position to free
            if(w[i]==UNIQUE_MAX_WEIGHT) return i;
        }
    //more than 1 positions with same weight
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        if(free[i]) //if position is free
            if(w[i]==0.7f) exist07=true;
    if(exist07)
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
            if(free[i]) //if position is free
                if(w[i]==0.4f) free[i]=false;

    int j=0;
    int rn=0;
    int[] tmp;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        if(free[i]) j++;
    if(j!=0) {
        tmp=new int[j];
        rn=r.nextInt(j);
        j=0;
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
            if(free[i]) tmp[j++]=i;
        return tmp[rn];
    }
    else {
        return -1; //else GAME OVER
    }
}
private void InitTable() {

    PosTable=new int[9][9];
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
            PosTable[i][j]=-1;
    PosTable[0][1]=2;
    PosTable[0][2]=1;
    PosTable[0][3]=6;
    PosTable[0][4]=8;
    PosTable[0][6]=3;
    PosTable[0][8]=4;
    PosTable[1][2]=0;
    PosTable[1][4]=7;
    PosTable[1][7]=4;
    PosTable[2][4]=6;
    PosTable[2][5]=8;
    PosTable[2][6]=4;
    PosTable[2][8]=5;
    PosTable[3][4]=5;
    PosTable[3][5]=4;
    PosTable[3][6]=0;
    PosTable[4][5]=3;
    PosTable[4][6]=2;
    PosTable[4][7]=1;
    PosTable[4][8]=0;
    PosTable[5][8]=2;
    PosTable[6][7]=8;
    PosTable[6][8]=7;
    PosTable[7][8]=6;

}
```

Comment: Thanks to all who tried to help, i finally got the answer. and that is i had to change the code of  startActivityForResult code in there i have to write Game.class instead of TTTActivity.class. Thanks Again friends :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in your Game.java

`startActivityForResult(new Intent(Game.this, Game.class), ACTIVITY_SELECTION);`

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the `onCreate()` of your Game Activity:

```
 startActivityForResult(new Intent(Game.this, TTTActivity.class), ACTIVITY_SELECTION);
```

So you have

TTTActivity ----Click Start----> Game (activity) --onCreate---> Start TTTActivity again!

Your game isn't not showing, but it just ping back immediately.

Comment: no actually if you will comment this line then whole application doesn't function correctly. All button appears with default false value and if i click on any button application got terminated suddenly. So my senior suggested me to add this line.

Comment: the default false value shouldn't be relating to the above line of code.. and the FC should be related to other error, please double check the logcat results.

Answer (score 0):

add this code...

```
 Button newButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.new_button);
    newButton.setOnClickListener(this);        

    Button exitButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
    exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and i don't think you want to do `'startActivityForResult(new Intent(Game.this, TTTActivity.class), ACTIVITY_SELECTION);`
' in `oncreate()`

Comment: where do i have to add this code? and i don't think so that it can help me with this activity problem. Please explain clearly

Comment: @VikasGupta .. intead of your **View newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
    newButton.setOnClickListener(this);        

    View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
    exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);**

Comment: actually if i dnt add that line then whole application doesn't function correctly. All button appears with default false value and if i click on any button application got terminated suddenly. So my senior suggested me to add this line.

Comment: and i have done that button changing thing but nothing happened. :(

Comment: remove **startActivityForResult(new Intent(Game.this, TTTActivity.class), ACTIVITY_SELECTION);** this line from **onCreate()** .. i don't think you want to do that there..

Comment: no man u are not getting this. actually activity changing happens but not in first time it happens in second time we click on new game. so if that line was wrong activity transfer wouldn't have happened. I think there is problem with remaining code in game activity.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it, there was some mistake in this code

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Game.this, TTTActivity.class), ACTIVITY_SELECTION);
```

It should be like this.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Game.this, Game.class), ACTIVITY_SELECTION);
```

Actually it needed to change activity from itself to itself. So it worked absolutely fine for me. BTW Thanks a lot to all who tried to help. :)